# NGINX Multiple servers same IP

Tags: nginx, server, virtual-hosts

I want to configure my server as follows:

- Just 1 server with 1 IP and,
- Just 1 domain pointing to that IP, lets say `example.com`
- Two different web applications running on nginx (on the same port 80), separated as `/site1` and `/site2`

Is it possible to configure `sites-available/site1` and `sites-available/site2` config files to access them through `http://example.com/site1` in the first case and `http://example.com/site2` in the second case??

Thanks!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: shared hosts run hundreds if not thousands of sites on a single server using exactly the method you describe. if you're not sure how to manually configure try one of the many web hosting control panels available

Answer (score 3):

You can separate them into 2 files but it would be a little tricky, because you're basically creating one website but configuring two locations, for example here's a skeleton

```
server {
  # listen 80 is default
  location /site1 {
    # do stuff
  }
  location /site2 {
    # do different stuff
  }
}
```

To separate this you need to include both location inside a server scope, not the http scope ( which happens by default )

so to do that you'd for **example** create a folder called `/etc/nginx/site-includes` and add `site1` and `site2` in them, then inside your site which is inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` you'd include them like this

```
server {
  # listen 80 is default
  include /etc/nginx/site-includes/site1;
  include /etc/nginx/site-includes/site2;
}
```

each file will include a `location` snippet

```
location /site1 {
  # do stuff
}
```

You could remove a dependency ( the file names ) by using wild cards

```
server {
  # listen 80 is default
  include /etc/nginx/site-includes/my-site/*;
}
```

Then add as many files inside the `/etc/nginx/site-includes/my-site/` directory.

Similar method is already used inside the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```